# Decorated function return type remains original when called directly

Tags: python, decorator, mypy, python-typing

Defining a decorator that takes `Callable[..., int]` and returns `Callable[..., str]` seems to not be understood by mypy

```
def decorator(wrapped: Callable[..., int]) -> Callable[..., str]:
    def wrapper() -> str:
        return str(wrapped())

    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo() -> int:
    return 0


def bar():
    x = foo()  # mypy sees x as int even though the decorator(foo)() returns str
```

Is there something I can do, so that the return type of `foo()` is not its original return type, but the return type specified by the decorator?

Edit: Simplified the example

Comment: Which version of mypy do you use? `mypy 0.790` shows no problems

Comment: I am using `mypy 0.910`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i see in last version of mypy (0.930): str not int

```
def decorator(wrapped: Callable[..., int]) -> Callable[..., str]:

    def wrapper() -> str:
        return str(wrapped())

    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo() -> int:
    return 0


def bar() -> None:
    x = foo()
    reveal_type(x)  # Mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
```

Comment: Have the same. How do you checked your mypy sees it as int?

Comment: I am using a mypy plugin in PyCharm which so far I thought would show type mismatches exactly like running mypy would throw them. Turns out in my case the IDE complains even though running mypy on the file succeeds. If I change the types to make the IDE happy then mypy complains, seems to be an issue with the plugin or my local setup